# Why isn't my checkbox event listener listening correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes, I've read the related posts on Stack Overflow. Still can't figure out why this isn't working.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="#finished-checker" value="value"> 
<label for="finished-check">Check if assessment is complete.</label>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#finished-checker').change(function(){
    console.log("this.checked = " + this.checked);//TEST
    $.post({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Answers/UpdateFinishedValue',
        data: { finished: this.checked },
        success: function (retobj) {
            console.log(retobj);//TEST
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error ...");
        }
    });
});
```

That `change` function isn't being invoked. I've also tried

```
$('#finished-checker').bind('change',function(){
    // ...
});
```

and I've tried putting these in `$(document).ready`s and yada yada.

fiddle of proof: https://jsfiddle.net/c83cd6ah/

Comment: Remove the `#` from the `id` attribute in the HTML -> `id="finished-checker"`

Comment: @adeneo I meant for that to be `ajax`. But it's not the problem  at hand.

Comment: No, the typo Josh pointed out probably is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#` from id of the checkbox `finished-checkerUse` and use `ajax` instead of `post`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Answers/UpdateFinishedValue',
    data: { finished: this.checked },
    success: function (retobj) {
        console.log(retobj);//TEST
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Error ...");
    }
});
```